# nth-child maths repeating 1 to 7

Tags: math, css-selectors

So I've just started looking into nth-child stuff, looks really useful but I've failed on my first implementation.

What I'm trying to do is basically a rainbow pattern, so p's 1 to 7 have different colours.  that bit works fine where it falls down is the 8th p.  I want 8 to match 1 (9 to match 2, 10 to match 3 etc.) however because it works on multiples it doesn't work.  8 is a multiple of 1 but also of 2 and 4 so I end up with the colour of 4 on 8.

I've done a [quick pen](http://codepen.io/DeadWhisky/pen/fFeBv) to have a look at.
The colours are applied to ::selection to highlight the text to see it.

There are a couple of solutions I can think of.
 - Repeat the CSS so instead of 1 to 7 I do 1 to 70.
 - Do a bit of a [javascript hack](http://css-tricks.com/reveal-a-background-image-upon-text-selection/) and display a repeating background image

If any mathematicians can explain if this is possible that would be great.

Comment: Errr... Not having seen quick pen before I went to have a play and assumed it would be like jsfiddle and that it would have saved a version of that. It looks like it actually just let me edit and save the link you gave... On the plus side it is now showing some background colours... on the minus side I kind of broke your demo... Sorry. I blame quick pen personally though. :)

Comment: Also as a more general note you should always put code into the question and not just linked on another page. That way if the demo goes down for any reason (err, like somebody accidentally vandalising it) the question remains valid.

Comment: Code pen is great, I prefer it to JSfiddle, I recommend giving it a try.  Don't worry if you've clicked save you've only saved your own version you haven't overwritten mine.

Comment: Good point. Will stick code in the question next time too.

Comment: OK. Weirdly when I did a forced refresh of the page it was still showing mine which is why I thought I'd overwritten yours. I feel better now about many things. And yeah, it does look pretty nice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry I've solved it :)

Basically I've set all of them to repeat on 7n but off set them with minus numbers.  For example for the 6th row I've used nth-child(7n-1)

I've updated the pen here too http://codepen.io/DeadWhisky/pen/fFeBv